# Are there free (or inexpensive) 4-part dictation resources?

Tags: ear-training, learning-resources

I am beginning to teach a new course, and I am seeking some sort of source of simple 4-part dictations that I can use with my class.  They have done harmonic dictation already, but have not had to notate inner parts in their previous course.  I no longer have access to an academic library, but would nevertheless like to avoid re-creating the wheel myself if I can pick up a simple resource elsewhere.

Are there any good, sequenced sources for 4-part harmonic dictations that I can use with my class?

Answer (score 3):

The above link is great if you want Bach. But if your class isn't ready for 7th/extended chords, 2ndary functions, modulations, +6 chords, Ns, and all the far corners of chromatic harmony, it seems the answer is a big fat no. The majority of undergraduate music students are not yet capable of dictating Bach chorales. I have been in the same boat and have just had to record and upload chorales myself for my students to practice 4 part dictation. Finding just a book with simpler chorales is a challenge in itself. I was however fortunate enough to find a book called "Aural Harmony" by A. Eugene Ellsworth that is filled with 4 part chorales that are categorized by use of specific chords. If there is any site out there with recordings of simpler chorales for dictation, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this question! I will check out that book. I'm still hoping for something online and sequenced, but it might just be wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2):

A complete collection of Bach chorales is here: http://www.kunstderfuge.com/bach/chorales.htm.

If that isn't enough, you could try David Cope's collection of 5000 (!!) chorales composed by computer software in the style of Bach. See http://artsites.ucsc.edu/faculty/cope/5000.html.

Comment: These aren't sequenced for instructional purposes, but this will do very nicely if I don't find other resources.  Particularly the Cope collection -- thank you!